# Lenovo Yoga 730 Wifi not working with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Wifi Card tl8822be

Tags: wireless

I just installed ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my Lenovo Yoga 730, and the wifi card is not being detected.  I've searched the askubuntu forum and have seen that others have had similar problems, however they were with different Yogas and different Ubuntu versions.  So far, I've downloaded the rtl8822be driver and unzipped it.  I have no idea where to go from here, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved in Ubuntu 19.04, so if you don't depend on installing the LTS version, please use the latest Ubuntu.

I had no problems installing Ubuntu 19.04 on lenovo yoga 730-15iwl:

[Install Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 730-15IWL with a i5-8265U CPU alongside Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182889/install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-730-15iwl-with-a-i5-8265u-cpu-alongside-windows/1182890#1182890)