# Install Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 730-15IWL with a i5-8265U CPU alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lenovo

Are there any problems installing Ubuntu on a Lenovo Yoga 730-15IWL?

I tried the USB-version and everything seemed to work fine in the temporary system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were no problems during install. Just install Ubuntu on a USB device with **UNetbootin** (This can keep the existing data on your USB device and just add the install-image as extra folders).

(I guess it will be exactly the same on Yoga 730-13IWL)

But these are the optimizations I did after install:

### Optimization for installation of Ubuntu On Lenovo Yoga 730-15IWL

#### turn off turbo-boost after 60s

The new Intel i5 CPU 8th generation is great in speed, but on the cost, that if there are some CPU-intense applications, the fan is running all the time, I tend to disable turbo-boost after the system is running as described here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547261/20661

#### Adapter for Ethernet, SDCARD

The Lenovo has no ethernet port and no sdcard reader slot, so it is useful to get a "USB 3.1-Hub with sd Ethernet-Adapter"

#### Base install of missing applications

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
apt install wmctrl dialog unp git fcgiwrap vlc audacious gimp gimp-help-de pidgin pidgin-otr haveged language-pack-de language-pack-de-base firefox-locale-de hunspell-de-de libreoffice-l10n-de thunderbird-locale-de inkscape fail2ban nullmailer rkhunter ncdu ccze dfc screen tmux tig git-gui emacs24-nox openssh-server nfs-kernel-server sshfs vagrant keepass2 workrave dolphin chromium-browser krusader krename kompare kate p7zip dhcping audacity ttf-mscorefonts-installer ubuntu-restricted-extras bro etckeeper xfce4-goodies redshift meld htop atop fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console gnupg2 nmap jq traceroute lzop jnettop ecryptfs-utils picard  w3m curl wine dconf-editor make gcc g++ unzip libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev subversion gawk bzip2 libssl-dev virtualbox openvpn yakuake onboard neovim python3-setuptools python3-pip tree psensor hardinfo kdiff3
```

#### Get rid of Amazon shopping lens

```
apt remove unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video
```

#### Background images

https://askubuntu.com/a/1145869/34298

#### Keyboard-layout

[Configure Caps Lock as AltGr and Arrows like in vim](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684459/configure-caps-lock-as-altgr-and-arrows-like-in-vim)

#### Fix nodejs

```
snap install --classic --edge node
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
snap install atom --classic
```

#### Fix scrolling in Firefox

https://askubuntu.com/a/994483

#### Show weekday and seconds in the gnome status bar

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-weekday true
```

### in case you use KDE or Kubuntu on Yoga 730-15IWL

[Plasmashell High CPU Load Fix - Plasma 5.15 KDE on Kubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162252/plasmashell-high-cpu-load-fix-plasma-5-15-kde-on-kubuntu-19-04)

#### Fix default app okular:

https://www.ryananddebi.com/2014/09/29/linux-fixing-pdfs-opening-in-gimp-in-firefoxzotero/

#### Add Rotate Screen on CTL+F8

Screen rotation works out-of-the-box on Ubuntu, you can turn it on and off in the top-right corner menu, but only 180°. If you need to rotate 90° you can add a shortcut to CTRL+F8 to rotate by setting

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings rotate-monitor "['XF86RotateWindows', '<Control>F8']"
```

see https://askubuntu.com/a/1184316/34298

#### Nvidia drivers only on-demand

Set the 'on-demand' option in the Nvidia GUI:
"Nvidia X Server Settings" -> "PRIME Profiles": NVIDIA On-Demand

[image]

## unsolved Problem

- My Network-Adapter Thunderbolt device is are not recognized on-plugin. I have to restart the laptop so it is registered, but I can live with that so far