# unable to boot in windows

Tags: boot, windows

I have installed 20.04 lts. I am not able to use Windows as it displays error as "boot configuration disk' damged. boot from installation disk. How do I overcome?

Comment: Is Windows an UEFI install? And then can you directly boot it from UEFI boot menu? Grub only boots working Windows, so when Windows updates & turns fast start up back on, grub will not boot it and you have to directly boot it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Thanks. I am able to boot thru boot menu. Also, I noticed that the members resulted in hanging of laptop at 52%. Does it mean that RAM is faulty and it could be the reason?

Comment: If Windows works, then hardware is not an issue. Could be partition needs chkdsk if NTFS or fsck if ext4. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks @oldfred. My laptop is Yoga pro 1370. I am not conversant with Ubuntu/Linux. U r right, freezing seems HW issue. Think I will get it rectified in few weeks time. Thanks for ur response.

Comment: Does this apply. Probably separate issue. ThinkPad models including the ThinkPad X1 Carbon (5th Gen to 7th Gen), X1 Yoga (2nd Gen to 4th Gen), and P-series 
https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/
 Lenovo Yoga S740     [SOLVED] Installation problem
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2433373
Lenovo Yoga 730-15IWL i5-8265U
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182889/install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-730-15iwl-with-a-i5-8265u-cpu-alongside-windows