# ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso installation fails on Laptop with NVMe drive

Tags: uefi, gpt, nvme, rufus

I am not able to install Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo laptop. Unfortunately, the installation stalls when I define the mount point, enter name and password to set up the computer name and then click on the "Continue" button. It does show some progress in the beginning and then it just stalls when it is "Detecting file systems ..."

In some cases, it stalls at a different point while the installation of "dpkg" is in progress.

I am using RUFUS to create a bootable ISO USB-PENDRIVE of 8GB. I have attached the log report. In BIOS, I have disabled secure boot and under booting I have selected "only UEFI" and "CSM = NO".

By setting CSM as No, I believe that is required as the I have selected GPT in RUFUS and the corresponding option is UEFI(no CSM).

The disk chosen for this installation is the NVMe based drive and I have allocated 536 MB for EFI partition and the rest formatted as ext4 and mounted on "/" for Ubuntu 20.04.

What am I missing? I have checked the download ISO image for integrity using the sha256, the image is good and I have changed almost 3 to 4 different pen drives.

Please let me know. I have attached the logs and images for your reference.

Thank you.

Here is the RUFUS log(I have removed some log entries due to post's code limit on Stackoverflow) and the images:

[stage at which installation stalls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SH6P.jpg)

[partition layout for efi and Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jkiu.jpg)

```
Rufus x86 v3.10.1647
Windows version: Windows 7 SP1 64-bit
Syslinux versions: 4.07/2013-07-25, 6.04/pre1
Grub versions: 0.4.6a, 2.04
System locale ID: 0x0409 (en-US)
Will use default UI locale 0x0409
SetLGP: Successfully set NoDriveTypeAutorun policy to 0x0000009E
Localization set to 'en-US'
Found USB 2.0 device 'JetFlash Transcend 8GB USB Device' (8564:1000)
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 8 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 984, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x19D22CBD
Drive has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 (0x0b)
  Size: 7.5 GB (8090648576 bytes)
  Start Sector: 8192, Boot: No
Scanning image...
ISO analysis:
  Image is an ISO9660 image
  Will use '/isolinux/isolinux.cfg' for Syslinux
  Detected Syslinux version: 6.04/20191223 (from '/isolinux/isolinux.bin')
Disk image analysis:
  Image has an unknown Master Boot Record
  Image is a bootable disk image
ISO label: 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64'
  Size: 2.5 GB (Projected)
  Has a >64 chars filename
  Uses: Syslinux/Isolinux v6.04
  Uses: EFI
  Note: This ISO uses symbolic links, which will not be replicated due to file system limitations.
  Because of this, some features from this image may not work...
Using image: ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso (2.5 GB)

Format operation started
Requesting disk access...
Will use 'E:' as volume mountpoint
Deleting partitions...
Deleting ALL partition(s) from disk '\\?\PhysicalDrive1':
● Partition 1 (offset: 4194304, size: 7.5 GB)
Opened \\.\PhysicalDrive1 for exclusive write access
Analyzing existing boot records...
Drive has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
Clearing MBR/PBR/GPT structures...
Erasing 128 sectors
Deleting partitions...
Partitioning (GPT)...
● Creating Main Data Partition (offset: 1048576, size: 7.5 GB)
Closing existing volume...
Waiting for logical drive to reappear...
Formatting (FAT32)...
Using cluster size: 4096 bytes
Quick format was selected
Creating file system...
Format completed.
Writing Master Boot Record...
Using Rufus protective MBR
Writing protective message SBR
Found volume \\?\Volume{4dc8172a-f36e-11e7-b5df-863a5a649a54}\
Successfully remounted \\?\Volume{4dc8172a-f36e-11e7-b5df-863a5a649a54}\ as E:
Extracting files...
Image is an ISO9660 image
This image will be extracted using Rock Ridge extensions (if present)
Extracting: E:\.disk\base_installable (0 bytes)
Extracting: E:\.disk\casper-uuid-generic (37 bytes)
Extracting: E:\.disk\cd_type (15 bytes)
Extracting: E:\.disk\info (57 bytes)
Extracting: E:\.disk\release_notes_url (78 bytes)
Extracting: E:\boot\grub\efi.img (3.9 MB)
Extracting: E:\boot\grub\font.pf2 (4.9 KB)
Extracting: E:\boot\grub\grub.cfg (911 bytes)
Extracting: E:\boot\grub\loopback.cfg (240 bytes)
Extracting: E:\boot\grub\x86_64-efi\acpi.mod (15.2 KB)
Extracting: E:\boot\grub\x86_64-efi\adler32.mod (2 KB)
Extracting: E:\boot\grub\x86_64-efi\ahci.mod (22.4 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-435\nvidia-dkms-435_435.21-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb (26.9 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-435\nvidia-driver-435_435.21-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb (404.9 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-435\nvidia-kernel-common-435_435.21-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb (9.0 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-435\nvidia-kernel-source-435_435.21-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb (11.9 MB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-435\nvidia-utils-435_435.21-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb (329.2 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-435\xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435_435.21-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb (1.4 MB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-cfg1-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (70.3 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-common-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_all.deb (10.3 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-compute-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (19.9 MB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-compute-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_i386.deb (20.7 MB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-decode-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (1002.4 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-decode-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_i386.deb (1 MB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-encode-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (37.8 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-encode-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_i386.deb (38.2 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-extra-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (37.6 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-fbc1-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (48.4 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-fbc1-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_i386.deb (45.6 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-gl-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (59.9 MB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-gl-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_i386.deb (16.0 MB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-ifr1-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (67.6 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\libnvidia-ifr1-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_i386.deb (60.8 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\nvidia-compute-utils-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (72.4 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\nvidia-driver-430_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (7.4 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\nvidia-driver-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (405.3 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\nvidia-kernel-common-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (20.2 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\nvidia-kernel-source-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (12.5 MB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\nvidia-utils-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (337.6 KB)
Extracting: E:\pool\restricted\n\nvidia-graphics-drivers-440\xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440_440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb (1.4 MB)
Extracting: E:\preseed\cli.seed (212 bytes)
Extracting: E:\preseed\ltsp.seed (497 bytes)
Extracting: E:\preseed\ubuntu.seed (460 bytes)
Extracting: E:\README.diskdefines (229 bytes)
Extracting: E:\ubuntu (0 bytes)
  Ignoring Rock Ridge symbolic link to '.'
Created: E:\syslinux.cfg → /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
Finalizing, please wait...
Created: E:autorun.inf
Created: E:autorun.ico

Found USB 2.0 device 'JetFlash Transcend 8GB USB Device' (8564:1000)
Using autorun.inf label for drive E: 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64'
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 8 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 984, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: GPT, NB Partitions: 1
Disk GUID: {4BB81686-7599-4D24-A370-79546D53219B}
Max parts: 128, Start Offset: 17408, Usable = 8094808576 bytes
Partition 1:
  Type: Microsoft Basic Data Partition
  Name: 'Main Data Partition'
  ID: {38DCCF9D-796A-48DB-BBC2-3F313FBC48F5}
  Size: 7.5 GB (8093777408 bytes)
  Start Sector: 2048, Attributes: 0x0000000000000000
Found USB 2.0 device 'JetFlash Transcend 8GB USB Device' (8564:1000)
Using autorun.inf label for drive E: 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64'
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 8 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 984, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: GPT, NB Partitions: 1
Disk GUID: {4BB81686-7599-4D24-A370-79546D53219B}
Max parts: 128, Start Offset: 17408, Usable = 8094808576 bytes
Partition 1:
  Type: Microsoft Basic Data Partition
  Name: 'Main Data Partition'
  ID: {38DCCF9D-796A-48DB-BBC2-3F313FBC48F5}
  Size: 7.5 GB (8093777408 bytes)
  Start Sector: 2048, Attributes: 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: Have you Updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Which model Lenovo? Which video? Lenovo Thinkpad 430s UEFI update 19.10 install
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2432688
Lenovo x390 'optimized os set up' must be off  Skip Windows parts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182889/install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-730-15iwl-with-a-i5-8265u-cpu-alongside-windows

Comment: This is Lenovo P72, I just updated the UEFI-BIOS, let me try SDD firmware, and then I will try installing Ubuntu.

Comment: @oldfred I updated the BIOS-UEFI, thank you for the tip. Unfortunately, I can't update the SSD firmware since the utility to update is only for Windows 10. There is no similar .iso image to update SSD firmware. After UEFI update, plugged in the bootable Ubuntu 20.04, and tried the option "Try Ubuntu" and its the same issue. No activity and looks like it is frozen. The cursor has disappeared and the time doesn't change.

Comment: @oldfred just to let you know the "Controller mode" is set to AHCI originally. So, I will be leaving that untouched since I would be adding an SSD SATA drive later once I have Ubuntu 20.04 up and running.

Comment: My new Samsung NVMe drive has an ISO that I was able to boot & use to update. Hardware now is starting to be update able from within Linux. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fwupd-NVMe-SSD-Support-Start & https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist & 
https://fwupd.org/vendorlist
 Those vendors that support UEFI update with Linux are those I consider as better vendors. See Dell & Lenovo, but more for newer hardware.