# How do I dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on a Lenovo Yoga?

Tags: 20.04

I'm sorry if this is a noob question. I have searched some online. But can't really figure out how. I think I have a weird BIOS.. I'm trying to change the BIOS security settings.

Comment: There is an "Install alongside" option... assuming desktop (you didn't say if you wanted desktop, server etc)

Comment: @guiverc Not really. I believe I have to change some BIOS security settings.

Comment: What model Yoga? Some examples: Lenovo Yoga 730-15IWL i5-8265U
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182889/install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-730-15iwl-with-a-i5-8265u-cpu-alongside-windows Lenovo Yoga S740     [SOLVED] Installation problem
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2433373 ThinkPad models including the ThinkPad X1 Carbon (5th Gen to 7th Gen), X1 Yoga (2nd Gen to 4th Gen), and P-series 
https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/ Lenovo Yoga 11s Needed this: acpi_backlight=vendor 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188199

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Welcome to the community :)

I would suggest you to follow the steps on this page: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

Best regards,
Martin